# How to change path of default Mobile View?

Tags: mobile-view

I have numerous subsites under my main site - all with Mobile View turned on.

When in mobile view, and selecting the link to the subsite, I am directed to the 'Site Contents' section of the subsite rather than the homepage.

How/where do I change this so I always land on the actual homepage of the subsite?

(SharePoint 2016)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After much googling and reading - it is not possible to change the destination path for the Mobile View template.

From what I read, it would seem that support for the Mobile View Template feature is very limited and there isn't much of a future for the feature as the majority of sites are now built with responsiveness.